# Fast way to solve $4 = \sqrt[3] {x+10}-\sqrt[3] {x-10}$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, radical-equations

The question is this:

$4 = \sqrt[3] {x+10}-\sqrt[3] {x-10}$

For some reason, I keep on getting 289/3, even though it is the wrong answer. This is from a timed test, and my way is wrong and extremely slow.

Comment: Show us how you got $289/3$.

Comment: @TonyK i defined $\sqrt[3] {x+10}$ as a and the other one as b,a and b to the third power is x+10 and x-10. This means a^3 -b^3 = 20. Factor a^3 -b^3 to get 
$a^2+ab+b^2 = 5$. $(a-b)^2$ is equal to 16. subtract $a^2+ab+b^2$ and $(a-b)^2$ to get 3ab=-11. This means ab = -11/3, making $x^2-100=-11/3$

Comment: @AlexR.: It has two real solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\sqrt[3]{x-10}=t$, then the equation is

$$4+t=\sqrt[3]{t^3+20}.$$

So $$64+48t+12t^2+t^3=t^3+20,$$ $$\iff 12t^2+48t+44=0,$$
which gives
$ t=(-24\pm \sqrt{48})/12=-2\pm \sqrt{3}/3$ and $$x=t^3+10=\pm 7.12065332001...$$

Comment: From your definition of $t$ it follows that $t > 0$ but $\sqrt{3}/3 - 2<0$ thus there are no real solutions.

Comment: @cgss: why does it follow that $t>0$?

Comment: No, the cube root can be negative. Say, $\sqrt[3]{-8}=-2$. You are confusing it with the square root.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't write $\sqrt[3]{-8}$. It seems I am wrong.

Comment: @cgss: Yes, you are wrong. What is $(-2)^3$? Therefore, what is $\sqrt[3]{-8}$?

Comment: You know I know it's $-8$. Instead of $\sqrt[3]{-8}$ I grew up taught to write $-\sqrt[3]{|-8|}$. I guess you would call that a formality(?). Anyways, I simply never changed that.

Answer (score 5):

Use this formula $$\boxed{(a-b)^3 = a^3-3ab(a-b)-b^3}$$

$$4 = \sqrt[3] {x+10}-\sqrt[3] {x-10}\;\;\;/^3$$

$$64 = x+10 -3\sqrt [3]{(x+10)(x-10)}(\underbrace{\sqrt[3] {x+10}-\sqrt[3] {x-10}}_{4})-x+10$$

So $$11 = -3\sqrt [3]{x^2-100}\implies x = \pm\sqrt{{-11^3\over 27}+100}$$

Comment: I like your approach. I still have a doubt about it. Your argument shows that any solution of the OP equation is an element of $\{\pm\sqrt{{11^3\over 27}+100}\}$. Does it also show that any element of $\{\pm\sqrt{{11^3\over 27}+100}\}$ solves the original equation?

Comment: Just plug it in original equation. @FormulaWriter

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) Of course one can directly check if the values found solve the equation. My doubt is: following your approach to find those values, is it superfluous to plug the values in the original equation? Is it obvious that both those values solve the equation?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $-3$ in the last line?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the cube on both sides,
$\implies 64 = 10 - 3(4)(x^2 - 100)^{1/3}$.

Note that $(x+10)^{1/3} - (x-10)^{1/3} = 4$

Thus, we get $x^2 = - \frac{1369}{27}$.

Hence, the roots are : 
$-\frac{37\sqrt3}{3}$  & $\frac{37\sqrt3}{3}$.